# Navigate to Specific UIViewController when back button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have four `ViewController` lets say **A** **B** **C** **D**.

**A** navigates to **B**, **B** can navigates to **C** and **D** both.

And **C** can navigate to **D**

And **D** can navigate to **C**

Now I want if I press back button in **C** **D** it goes back to **B** always.

I am navigating using a sague like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hourlyToPeriodic" sender:self];
```

Please ask if anything is un clear.

Comment: You can use `viewControllers` property of the `UINavigationController` to find the viewController B and `popToViewController:animated:` to go to it. A way then, could be to subclass the navigation controller, and check when it's C or D that is asking to pop, go to B instead of C or D depending on the hierarchy if one of them was the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pushed to **C** or **D** view controllers you can

**modify navigation stack:**

```
NSMutableArray *navigationStack = [D.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *navigationStack = [C.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
```

**Remove no need view controllers from stack**

```
[navigationStack removeObject:D];
```

or

```
[navigationStack removeObject:C];
```

**And set new navigation stack**

```
[D.navigationController setViewControllers:navigationStack animated:NO];
```

or

```
[C.navigationController setViewControllers:navigationStack animated:NO];
```

And if you will press back button you will return to **B**

Or use the way as a @Larme answered

Comment: NSMutableArray *navigationStack = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [navigationStack removeObject:self];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:navigationStack animated:NO];

Comment: wrote this after performSegueWithIdentifier line solved my problem